# Real-time display of events from EventProviderTraceListener in traceview

Tags: c#, trace, etw

I am looking for a way to see the events logged using EventProviderTraceListener in real time. I am able to use logman to start & stop the tracing session and then decode the resulting .etl file, but I would like to see the events as they arrive.

Here is the sample C# class that I am using for testing:

```
public class TraceTest
{
    private static Guid ProviderGuid = new Guid("{2EC22694-F8D3-4066-B089-300DF0749C71}");
    private static EventProviderTraceListener listener = new EventProviderTraceListener(ProviderGuid.ToString(), Test Listener", "::");
    private static TraceSource source = new TraceSource("TestSource", SourceLevels.All);

    public TraceTest()
    {
        source.Listeners.Add(listener);

        source.TraceInformation("Tracing prototype.");
    }
}
```

Using traceview, I am able to start new tracing session by inputing the guid, but I don't know where to look for tmf files in order to be able to decode the messages - I see them arriving, but they are logged with "No Format Information found".

Comment: try this instead: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not directly log to ETW you can write your own [TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener(v=vs.110).aspx) and add it like you add the EventProviderTraceListener (see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21009/A-Simple-TextBox-TraceListener)) or use your app.config (see [here](https://wintrace.codeplex.com/)). Or you can do it using ETW, like logman and traceview, with [ETWTraceEventSource](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent/) like [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2012/12/20/and-end-to-end-etw-tracing-example-eventsource-and-traceevent.aspx), but that requires administrator rights to start the trace.

Comment: I am fine with requiring the administrator rights in order to start and stop traces. I will take a look at the ETWTraceEventSource, but I really hoped that there is some existing solution (like making it work in traceview) or tool shipped by Microsoft.

Comment: I ended up writing my own simple reader for traces since I could not make traceview work.